# Unity - Loading asset bundles - File can't be loaded because it is not compatible with this platform

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity app that loads asset bundles from my htdocs, one that is to run on an iPhone.

While the content acquisition works (afaik), the loading stops about halfway and Xcode spits out the following error:

```
Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 13.037000 ms

Unloading 50 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 733.
Total: 10.006415 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.065750 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.033250 ms MarkObjects: 0.951208 ms  DeleteObjects: 8.955166 ms)

2016-10-26 18:34:58.882 CookieJarApp[6245:1953469] You are using download over http. Currently unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
Asset bundle [ios_cookie_prefabs] loaded.
<CoLoadAssetBundle>d__20:MoveNext()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

The file can not be loaded because it was created for another build target that is not compatible with this platform.
Please make sure to build AssetBundles using the build target platform that it is used by.
File's Build target is: 13

<CoLoadAssetBundle>d__20:MoveNext()

[ line 907] 
(Filename:  Line: 907)

The AssetBundle 'http://192.168.1.241:80/CookieJarApp_test/ios_cookie_prefabs' can't be loaded because it was not built with the right version or build target.
<CoLoadAssetBundle>d__20:MoveNext()

[ line 406] 
(Filename:  Line: 406)

NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
  at AssetBundleController.GetGameObject (System.String bundleID, System.String objectName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AssetBundleController.UnloadAll () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Loader+<LoadPrefabs>c__AnonStorey22.<>m__15 (UnityEngine.AssetBundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AssetBundleController+<CoLoadAssetBundle>d__20.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

However, I built the prefab (another game in itself) with iOS platform selected in Build Settings.

I've been told it's different for asset bundles, is there anything else I can try?

Here's the `CoLoadAssetBundle` function:

```
// Start a download of the given URL
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("[" + bundleId + "] Progress:" + www.progress * 100f + "%");
            yield return null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log("Asset bundle [" + bundleId + "] loaded.");
            m_assetBundleList.Add(new AssetBundleStruct(bundleId, www.assetBundle));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Asset bundle [" + bundleId + "] not loaded!\n[" + www.error + "]");
        }

        www.Dispose();
```

Comment: Where is the code you used to load the Asset bundle?

Comment: @Programmer, ah, it's not with me at the moment, I'll have to update this when I get back tomorrow. FWIW, we've used the same code to create at least one Asset Bundle that works flawlessly, to I didn't think there would be a problem there.

Comment: @Programmer, I've added some code, hopefully it helps.

Comment: I was talking about the code you use to **load** it from the device not the code you use to **build** it. At the-same time, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Programmer, my mistake, sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: Look at my answer. I don't think you've checked it. I edited it to show you what to replace. That should work, otherwise leave a comment under it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to force caching to use new copy of the `AssetBundle` after building it  for iOS.

You can do this by provide the second parameter(`int version`) if you are using the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) API.

```
WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url, 1);
```

If using the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) API, you must provide the third parameter(`uint version`) to it's static constructor.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(url, 0, 1);
```

**EDIT**:

With your edited question and code, you need to use the first method I mentioned in this answer. Simply replace

`WWW www = new WWW(url);` **with** `WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url, 1);`

Comment: I changed that part to the code you suggested (thanks, btw). It's still giving me the same error, however.

Comment: That's weird. Why not replace the `1` with `2` and see what happens. Also uninstall the old app from iOS before building a new one